# Angular: Call method after DOM update

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-scope

I am calling a method(which calls a rest service) from html to increment/decrement a count on the screen. Now I want to call another method (i.e. getThreshold) to check if the count reaches a threshold value. If yes I want to show a confirmation message.

I want to update the count on the screen first then call the function to check if it reaches the threshold. But now it is calling the function and rest call first, then updating the count on the screen.

I have to show a confirm dialog before I call the next rest call. But the dialog is showing up before updating the count on the screen.

So here is my code:

component.html

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a [routerLink]="" (click)="updateCount(inspect, 'A', 'M')" class="btn btn-success">A-</a></td>
  </tr>
  </table
```

component.ts

```
updateCount(inspection, rankName: string, rankPlusOrMinus: string) {
  inspection.rankName = rankName;
  inspection.rankPlusOrMinus = rankPlusOrMinus;
  const url = '/api/xyz';
  this.http
    .post(url, JSON.stringify(inspection), {
      headers: this.headers
    })
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => {
      let data = response.json();
      if (rankName = 'A') inspection.rankAcount = data.rankAcount;   // if I call getThreshold from here, it calls the function and rest call and displays alert message. But the count in A is NOT incremented yet
    })
    .catch(error => {}
    }

  getThreshold(rankName: string, rankAcount: number) {
    const url = '/api/threshold';
    this.http
      .get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        // Some Logic
        // Show alert message
      })
      .catch(error => {});
  }
}
```

Comment: check the answer. There are two possible ways. I guess in your case timeout should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flatMap for ordering APIs as:

```
updateCount(inspection, rankName: string, rankPlusOrMinus: string) {
    this.sendToServer(inspection, rankName, rankPlusOrMinus).flatMap((countResult) => {
        // Here you can update your view
        inspection.rankAcount = countResult.rankAcount;
        return this.http.get('/api/threshold').subscribe(response => {
                    // Some Logic
                    // Show alert message
                                    setTimeout(() => {alert('hi');});
               });
            }
        }
    );
}

sendToServer(inspection, rankName, rankPlusOrMinus) {
    inspection.rankName = rankName;
    inspection.rankPlusOrMinus = rankPlusOrMinus;
    const url = '/api/xyz';
    this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(inspection), {headers: this.headers}).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

**Solution 2**

add `timeout` after first API's response:

```
...
if (rankName = 'A') inspection.rankAcount = data.rankAcount;
setTimeout(() => {
    this.getThreshold(rankName, rankAcount);
});
...
```

Comment: I am a little confused in first solution. Can you please explain a little more.

Comment: @SKumar so in first solution, you send the data to server by calling `sendToServer ` that returns `Observable`. Here `flatMap` is being used that where `threshold` api will be called. Did it worked for you?

Comment: No, I have to show a confirm dialog before I call the next rest call. But the dialog is showing up before updating the count on the screen.

Comment: Your second solution works. I mean if I write an alert() inside setTimeout(), then it works. But if I call getThreshold funtion. it throws error. Cannot read property 'getThreshold' of undefined

Comment: you can use first solution and display the alert in timeout.

Comment: honestly, I could not understand the first solution. not tried yet.

Comment: OK, can you create a stackblitz/plunker? Let's fix it together over there.

Comment: You are asking difficult questions... again honestly I don't know ow to create an angular plunkr etc... Thanks for helping me. Can we discuss in a chat ?

Comment: I really want to resolve this now. If you can help me now, that would be great. I am sure I am missing something silly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168966/discussion-between-anshuman-jaiswal-and-skumar).

Comment: the second solution (i.e. setTimeout ) gave a big hint. So I am accepting this answer.

Comment: here you can find stackblitx: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-alert-after-view-update?file=app/hello.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to edit the API, I think it makes sense to return the threshold in a JSON object as a result of the first POST. That way you will not have to make a separate call to get the threshold. You could also just return a Boolean for whether or not the threshold is hit.

Example:

```js
this.http
  .post(url, JSON.stringify(inspection), {
    headers: this.headers
  })
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => {
    let data = response.json();
    let threshold = data.threshold;
    let result = data.inspection;
    if (rankName = 'A') {
      inspection.rankAcount = result.rankAcount;
      if (result.rankAccount == threshold) {
        //confirmation box here.
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {}
  }
```

Comment: No, I don't have access to backend.

Comment: The confirm box shows up before updating the value on the screen