# Angular use of $timeout

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808438/angular-call-method-after-dom-update), I am still struggling. So after googling a lot, I am thinking of using $timeout. I am open to any other suggestion.

My final goal is to show alert message to user ONLY after updating the count on the screen.

I am not getting how to use $timeout. I am getting **error**:

> Argument of type '(res: any, $timeout: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Inspection) => void | PromiseLike'

I have changed the code a little after I posted my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808438/angular-call-method-after-dom-update). I have added a Boolean element to my REST call to verify if the count reaches threshold and I have moved the actual REST call to Service.ts

With below code I am getting alert message before updating the count on the screen
component.ts

```
updateCount(inspection, rankName: string, rankPlusOrMinus: string)
    {
        inspection.rankName = rankName;
        inspection.rankPlusOrMinus = rankPlusOrMinus;
        this.inspectionService
            .update(inspection).then(function(res) {
                  alert("Reached Threshold: " + res.thresholdReached);
              })
              .catch(function(rej) {
                console.log(rej);
              });
    }
```

service.ts

```
  update(inspection: Inspection): Promise<Inspection> {
        const url = '/api/inspection/updatecount/';
        let rankName = inspection.rankName;
        return this.http
            .post(url, JSON.stringify(inspection), {headers: this.headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                //this.alertService.success(`Successfully created associate "${associate.name}"!`, true);
                let data = response.json();
                if (rankName='A') inspection.rankAcount = data.rankAcount;
                if (rankName='B') inspection.rankBcount = data.rankBcount;
                if (rankName='C') inspection.rankCcount = data.rankCcount;
                return response.json() as Inspection;
            })
            .catch(error => {
            });
    }
```

Getting error when I pass $timeout in component.ts

```
updateCount(inspection, rankName: string, rankPlusOrMinus: string)
{
    inspection.rankName = rankName;
    inspection.rankPlusOrMinus = rankPlusOrMinus;
    this.inspectionService
        .update(inspection).then(function(res, $timeout) {
            $timeout(function layout() {
              alert(res.thresholdReached);
            }, 30);
        })
              .catch(function(rej) {
                console.log(rej);
              });
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `$timeout`? That is an AngularJS (aka Angular v1.x) thing. You are using Angular (aka Angular v2.x+) so just use the `setTimeout(...)` browser method.

Comment: I am really new in Angular. I am using Angular 4. A code may help me a lot..thanks

Comment: Really surprised why a minus vote??? I have put all code I tried and explained what is the problem I am facing. The frustrating thing is there is no comment why there is a minus vote...

Comment: @SKumar your post seriously lacks research if you don't know that AngularJS is not the same framework as Angular, and if you somehow managed to think that $timeout is part of Angular. That's basically equivalent of trying to use a piece of C++ code you found on the internet in a Java program.

Comment: If I'm correct, you are trying to get some number from "/api/inspection/updatecount/"? And whr you get that number, you will try to get threshold? Confirm this so I can help you.

Comment: I have screen where user clicks A+ or A-. Before I increment in database and on the screen, I have to execute some business logic and based on that I may increase 1 or 2 or 3 etc. I have another table where threshold is there. in the same call, I am checking if it reached the threshold. If yes, I am setting reachedThreshold=true in the same REST response. Now I want to show user an alert message.

Comment: I am getting the count and rechedThreshold=true or false in same rest call, i.e. /api/inspection/updatecount/

Comment: @JBNizet: Honestly I got to know that AngularJS and Angular goes in almost 180 degree direction just few weeks back. And very honestly I am working on this since past 3 hours to show the alert message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it you need to change your code in updateCount cause then method has only one parameter

```
    updateCount(inspection, rankName: string, rankPlusOrMinus: string)
    {
        inspection.rankName = rankName;
        inspection.rankPlusOrMinus = rankPlusOrMinus;
        this.inspectionService
            .update(inspection).then(function(res) {
setTimeout(_=>  alert(res.thresholdReached) , 300); //change code here
            })
                  .catch(rej =>    console.log(rej));
        }
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer for now as it working for me now. I am open for other suggestion as well. Since we are passing a time to show the alert message, I am a little concerned. Because when the data grows and when the page complexity grows, it may take more time to update the data on the screen.

Comment: Could you please advice how to call another function instead of alert(). In that case I can show a confirm dialog and if the user agrees I can call another REST service.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your service.ts should look like:

```
updateCount(inspection: string, rankName: string, rankPlusOrMinus: string) {
    let bodyString = JSON.stringify({ inspection: inspection, rankName: rankName, rankPlusOrMinus: rankPlusOrMinus});
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });
    return this._http.post<any>(url, bodyString, { headers: headers });
}

getThreshold(rankName: string, rankAcount: number) {
    let params = new HttpParams()
        .append('rankName', rankName)
        .append('rankAcount', rankAcount.toString());
    return this._http.get<any>(url, { params: params });
}
```

This is how your component should look like:

```
this.inspectionService.updateCount(inspection, rankName, rankPlusOrMinus)
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .subscribe(
        data => { // here you update your counter },
        error => { this.errorMessage = <any>error; },
        () => { 
            // Here you check threshold, beacuse this part of code will run last 
            this.inspectionService.getThreshold(rankName, rankAcount)
                .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
                .subscribe(
                    data => { // here you do your threshold part 
                    alert("Reached Threshold: " + res.thresholdReached); },
                    error => { this.errorMessage = <any>error; },
                    () => {});
    });
```